# No sound icon in parameters or topbar

Tags: settings, wingpanel, sound

My sound works fine (I can control it with the keyboard and hear the music), but there is no longer an icon in the topbar or in the settings.

I'm pretty sure it's related to the fact that I installed an older version of libpulse0 and it removed a lot of packages, but I don't know which package I should reinstall to have my sound settings back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured out that `sudo apt install --reinstall elementary-desktop` resolved my problem